# how to solve No serialization error of jackson?

Tags: spring-boot, jackson-databind

I have problem in my movie web project
I'm implementing the storage of a movie's show schedule entity.

The part where the error occurred is as follows:
[image]

Im trying to import the Id values ​​of hall and movie into dto and use them to create schedule entity after creating hall and movie objects.

The error message is as follows:
`jackson.databind.exc.InvalidDefinitionException: No serializer found for class org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.bytebuddy.ByteBuddyInterceptor and no properties discovered to create BeanSerializer (to avoid exception, disable SerializationFeature.FAIL_ON_EMPTY_BEANS) (through reference chain: com.example.movie_ver2.core`

The problem occurs in the theater of the hall entity, and I think it occurs because theater cannot be called due to the fetch.lazy option.
[image]

I've looked up several references, but I'm not sure what the right way is. I think it may be a structural problem with my method, so I'd like to hear your opinions.

What I want to ask is

1. Is it correct to create the schedule object in the current way?
2. If there is no problem with the save method, how do I resolve the jackson serialization error?

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you